# CIFS Random file loading issue with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, io, cifs

I am having an issue running a rails application through CIFS.

The files are located on a windows 7 host. I am trying to run them on a ubuntu 13.10 VMWare guest through CIFS.

When running the *rails server* command I get **LoadError**s on random files at startup.

For example:

```
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load': cannot load such file -- /mnt/VMWareShared/IncidentSmart/config/initializers/rolify.rb (LoadError)
```

Then sometimes the server will start but  I will get I/O errors when accessing the server.

```
Unexpected error while processing request: Input/output error - /mnt/VMWareShared/IncidentSmart/public/assets/headlineimg.jpg
```

I have thrown the kitchen sink into the fstab entry, but I must be doing something wrong.

```
//192.168.1.106/VMWareShared /mnt/VMWareShared cifs username=ubuntu,password=ubuntu,uid=dan,gid=dan,nounix,rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced very similar issue with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.10. I found that downgrading SMB protocol version can help.

You can do it by adding `vers=2.0` to the options of mount command like this:

```
mount -t cifs -o rw,vers=2.0,uid=1000 //server/share /mnt/share
```

For me it works so far.